# Azure Continuous Delivery fails on build

Tags: azure, msbuild

I get the following error when a build is run

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2221,5): Error : Copying file web.config to obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\original\web.config failed. Could not find file 'web.config'.

I've checked and the web.config file is in the repository.

I'm quite new to working with CI/CD, ms build so i don't know why i get this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of build agent are you running? "Hosted 2017"?

Answer (score 0):

Double check to make sure the account that is running the build has access to the folder where the web.config is located.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the console output from the failed build, it told me that it was looking for a web.config placed in a folder somewhere in the solution. This web.config file was Ignored according to my solution explorer in Visual Studio.

After "deleting" the file in the solution explorer, the solution could build

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on an old project (MVC 2) by replacing the build step.

Before:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
```

After:

```xml
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" ToolPath="$(AspNetToolPath)" />
</Target>
```